# How to assign to a Fragment a controller?

Tags: sapui5

I have the following view, that contains a fragment:

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:smartFilterBar="sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar"
    controllerName="ch.mindustrie.ZMM_OBJECTS_CLASSES.controller.ClassSelection" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar id="SelectionFilterBar" entitySet="ZMM_C_CLASSIFICATION" search="onSearchClass">
        <smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
            <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="ClassType" preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
            <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="ClassNum" preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
        </smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
    </smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar>
    <core:Fragment fragmentName="ch.mindustrie.ZMM_OBJECTS_CLASSES.fragment.Tree" id="TreeFm" type="XML"/>
</mvc:View>
```

Then, I want to assign to the fragment a controller:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "ch/mindustrie/ZMM_OBJECTS_CLASSES/controller/BaseController",
    "ch/mindustrie/ZMM_OBJECTS_CLASSES/helper/Message",
    "ch/mindustrie/ZMM_OBJECTS_CLASSES/controller/TreeFragment.controller"
], function (BaseController, Message, TreeController) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseController.extend("ch.mindustrie.ZMM_OBJECTS_CLASSES.controller.ClassSelection", {
        onInit: function () {

        },

        onSearchClass: function () {
            const aFilter = this.byId("SelectionFilterBar").getFilters();
        },
    });
});
```

The `TreeController` controller should be assigned to the fragment with the id `TreeFm` from above. How can I assign a controller to the fragment?

I considered the function `sap.ui.core.Fragment.load`, but I think it is not suitable for my case.

Comment: Fragments do not have their own controllers, this requires the Fragments to be used within a View which does have a controller.That controller is used

Comment: So it is not possible to add a controller to a fragment?

Comment: If the fragment is part of the view like in your example then the controller of the view is also the controller of the fragment. If you want a second controller you should use a nested view, not a nested fragment.

Comment: Related feature request: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2355